# Routing between 2 networks on Linux

Tags: routing, linux-networking, dhcp, dnsmasq, nmcli

My system topology:

On an ubuntu machine with 2 ethernet ports (eth0, eth1) i have connected another ubuntu machine as client and an OCRCamera (also client).

the requirement is that the main ubuntu machine will be DHCP server and router, so that the ubuntu-client and the camera will both get IP address from the main ubuntu machine.
The ubuntu-client and the camera need to be able to ping/ssh one another.

with nmcli commands and configuration file in "/etc/dnsmasq.d/X", i have configured both eth0 and eth1 on the main ubuntu machine in a shared mode:

**"/etc/dnsmasq.d/XXX" config file:**

```
no-resolv
port=53
bogus-priv
strict-order
expand-hosts

domain=wombat.pixellot.com

# Set Listen address
listen-address=192.168.101.1
dhcp-range=set:group1,192.168.101.10,192.168.101.100,24h
dhcp-option=tag:group1,option:router,192.168.101.1
dhcp-option=tag:group1,option:dns-server,192.168.101.1
dhcp-option=tag:group1,option:netmask,255.255.255.0

listen-address=192.168.102.1
dhcp-range=set:group2,192.168.102.10,192.168.102.100,24h
dhcp-option=tag:group2,option:router,192.168.102.1
dhcp-option=tag:group2,option:dns-server,192.168.102.1
dhcp-option=tag:group2,option:netmask,255.255.255.0
```

**nmcli commands:**

```
sudo nmcli connection add type ethernet ifname eth0 ipv4.method shared con-name EthCon0
sudo nmcli connection add type ethernet ifname eth1 ipv4.method shared con-name EthCon1

sudo nmcli connection modify EthCon0 ipv4.addresses 169.254.101.1/24
sudo nmcli connection modify EthCon1 ipv4.addresses 169.254.101.2/24

sudo nmcli connection up EthCon0
sudo nmcli connection up EthCon1
```

This is how ifconfig on the main ubuntu machine looks like:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.101.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.101.255
        inet6 fe80::c706:5a57:f51d:a8b0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 48:b0:2d:3b:6d:0b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 76802  bytes 6700303 (6.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 8  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 73153  bytes 7426646 (7.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 37  

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.102.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.102.255
        inet6 fe80::cf74:51de:1317:fe42  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ae:aa:82:3c:08:6c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 41  bytes 4289 (4.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 187  bytes 29743 (29.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The ubuntu client, and the camera connected to eth0 and eth1 respectively, got an ip addressed, and pinging is available:

```
pixellot@wombat:~$ sudo ping 192.168.101.98
PING 192.168.101.98 (192.168.101.98) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.101.98: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.581 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.101.98: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.569 ms

pixellot@wombat:~$ sudo ping 192.168.102.32
PING 192.168.102.32 (192.168.102.32) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.102.32: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.451 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.102.32: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.508 ms
```

but, when i'm trying to ping from the ubuntu-client to the camera, it wont work:

```
yvesh@yvesh-XPS-15-9510:~$ ping 192.168.102.32
PING 192.168.102.32 (192.168.102.32) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.101.98 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.101.98 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
```

How can i make both clients communicate with each-other?
Is there any routing solution to this issue? (Not ssh-tunneling)
i have tried many things but i am stuck real bad on it and cant develop further :-(
Please help! <3

Comment: two things: `ip_forward` is enabled? Do you have a firewall ( `ufw` f.e.) in place on your "ubuntu router" ?

Comment: @Martin yes ipv4_forward is enabled, and there is no firewall anywhere in the system.